# How to scrape data from thousands of websites with different html structure (so maybe without using html tag) with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, regex, web, screen-scraping

My job is to extract information from all festival websites of my country.

Information such as postal address, the city or main topic of the festival as cinema, music, dance and so on.

However, not all websites have the same HTML structure; that is, they don't have the same HTML tags.

So data that I am looking for are mainly in the text content of the page, and the data can not be so easy to find because this is not clearly mentioned on every website like "address : 10 street of New York , New York".

Sometimes, there is no postal address on the website, or sometimes they mentioned several cities, so I can extract the wrong city.

I thought about using regex, or find a solution to send a global request to google and get data from others website. But is there any other "clean" solution or easy one with Node.js?

Comment: Voting to reopen since answers to this question do not HAVE to be entirely opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "clean" way to scrape HTML data from a bunch of web sites that you don't control.  HTML scraping is always messy.  You have to just evaluate each site independently and attempt to find the most reliable way to get the info you want.  And, you will need to know that it will probably break over time as these other sites modify their HTML and you will need regular maintenance to keep it up to date and working.

> How much time you think it will take to do this ?

How much time this will take is entirely dependent upon a whole bunch of things which we have no idea such as your skill level, the number of sites you're trying to scrape and the difficulty at finding a reliable way to get the data you want from each site.

> I thought about using regex, or find a solution to send a global request to google and get datas from others website? but there is any other "clean" solution or easy one with nodejs?

FYI, HTML does not generally lend itself well to a regex as the regex can easily break with minor HTML changes.  A more manageable way to get data from HTML is to parse it with something like [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) and then access the actual structure of the HTML directly, devising DOM queries that help you find the info you want.

And, if the content you want access to is generated via client-side Javascript and inserted into the page that way, then you will have to "run" the web page in order to get access to the content because the desired content isn't actually in the page's HTML.  This is often done with something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) which runs the web page in chromium (including running the Javascript in the page) and then gives you access to the DOM that way.

Comment: Thank you Jfriend00 for your answer ! I mean I want to get information from text content of elements each page of each website to find in the text content datas I need (address, topic...) When I say text content is text inside a paragraph for exemple, <p> hello world </p> here I would like to search in "hello world" content the address, I don't know if it's clear...

Comment: @Leonie - Every site is different so for any specific advice about how to find a particular piece of data in a particular web page, you'd have to post a link to the precise web page and tell us which data you're trying to get from it.  Then, we could offer ideas on how to best fetch that data.

Comment: Ok so I can give you three as examples : https://nordsudfilms.com/fr/cinema-a-la-frontiere/, http://www.tangosud-montpellier.com/, https://filmfrancophone.fr/fr, and I need to extract complete address with postcode, region, city, festival dates, festival creation date,  topic of the festival.

Comment: @Leonie - Those sites are a pain.  They aren't using very much semantics or data structure in their HTML, but rather using HTML mostly just for formatting.  In the nordfilms site, you could use cheerio and run a selector for `"article .entry-content p"` and iterate through the contents of each `<p>` tag in that selector to find that ones that have a format like they are using here.  The HTML, classes and ids do not point to the data you want so you have to get approximately there with a CSS selector and then iterate through the content to find what you're looking for.

Comment: @Leonie - In the nordfilms site, you could look through the targeted `<p>` tags either looking for the bullets or looking for the dates.  You could find dates in the textContent of a `<p>` tag with a regex where the regex targets text content, not HTML.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why I thougth about extract only the text contentf first and use regex to get datas I need. But there is not html structure and tags... thank you for your advice ;)

Comment: how much can I charge the customer for this kind of job ? and how much time I need what do you think ? thank you

Comment: @Leonie - I have no idea.  I would have to investigate a specific site and a specific objective to be able to estimate my own time in order to scape the data they were interesting in.  There are easy ones and hard ones and some sites/methods are more likely to remain working over time and others are likely to break because of the design of the site.

Comment: Yes I understand. These is the problem because there is hundreds of festivals website, all of them have a different structure and they want like 13 informations for all of them (address, post code, topic of the festival etc...) as it is in freelance I thought about more than 7000 euros in 2 months (the client told me that they want to finish in march or april)...